# Oracle: Execute query from a SELECTed String

Tags: oracle, select, execute

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || uc.table_name || ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' || uc.constraint_name FROM user_constraints uc WHERE constraint_type = 'R';
```

returns i.e. some statements which I can execute manually like:

```
ALTER TABLE APPLICATIONUSERROLE DROP CONSTRAINT APP_APPUSERROLE_FK1                       
ALTER TABLE APPLICATIONUSERROLE DROP CONSTRAINT USER_APPUSERROLE_FK1                      
ALTER TABLE APPLICATIONUSERROLE DROP CONSTRAINT ROLE_APPUSERROLE_FK1
```

What do I have to do to execute them automatically?

For example I tried:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || uc.table_name || ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' || uc.constraint_name FROM user_constraints uc WHERE constraint_type = 'R');
```

but thats not working at all throwing some errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin
   for i in (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || uc.table_name || ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' || uc.constraint_name as sql_text FROM user_constraints uc WHERE constraint_type = 'R')
     loop
       execute immediate i.sql_text;
     end loop;
end;
```

Comment: thanks, but throws: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SQL"

Comment: I edited post. try user sql_text alias instead of sql

Comment: thanks, now throws: PLS-00302: component 'sql_text' must be declared ;)

Comment: Are you sure that you added alias 'as sql_text' in your query:  "'ALTER TABLE ' || uc.table_name || ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' || uc.constraint_name **as sql_text"**

Comment: ah, blind. Thanks mate!